# How to get the next greatest value in an unordered set from Excel

Tags: excel, match, lookup

See below an example Excel with 3 col's.
Col A is the day number. Col B is the amount sold for that day. Col C is the next day the amount sold on that current day is exceeded next.

Col C is what I'm trying to work out. The importance being it is not ordered and I want the next highest? I've tried the match function but that doesn't seem to work

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You could create a column showing the RANK() of each value within the list, then use VLOOKUP() or INDEX() and MATCH() to find the date corresponding to the next-ranked value.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't give you the next highest sales day. e.g if sales were 5,3,4,7,2,10,8. 
 On Day 4 when sales are 7, Day 5 is when it is greater than Day 4 but doing the rank would give Day 6.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't paying close enough attention. I think you'll need to use an array formula that looks at all the rows below the current row (use relative referencing for the start of the range and absolute referencing for the end). You should be able to do that based on [this page](https://www.exceltip.com/lookup-formulas/retrieving-the-first-value-in-a-list-that-is-greater-smaller-than-a-specified-number.html). (In newer versions of Excel you may not need to press ctrl-shift-enter as shown there.)

Comment: No worries and thanks for your help. Only issue with that page is that the table needs to be ordered ascending, if not ordered then it doesn't work. The data I have is sales generated per day so won't be in an exact order by number

Comment: I think that had a formula where you use MATCH() to find TRUE in an array of TRUE/FALSE values. In that case, you can use 0 for the last argument of MATCH (exact match), and then the array doesn't have to be sorted -- MATCH will return the index of the first exact match, i.e. the first row where the test in the array formula is TRUE.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Realized I wasn't converting the formula into an array which is why it wasn't working. (Had to CTRL + Shift + Enter!

Answer (score 1):

I made your data into a **Table** so as to have the benefit of dynamic range names, but you could use regular addressing if you prefer.

- Create an array that starts at the current row and extends to the last row in the range.
- Compare the elements of the array with the Sales in the current row
- Use `MATCH` to return the first `TRUE` comparison (the greater than)
- Return the `Day` from the first column

```
=IFERROR("Day " & INDEX([@Day]:INDEX([Day],COUNT([Day])),
         MATCH(TRUE,[@Sales]:INDEX([Sales],COUNT([Sales]))>[@Sales],0)),
         "-")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. [Day] and [Sales], are they the arrays from A2-A7 / B2-B7? and are the @Day and @ Sales the specific days cell, e.g for Day 1 @ Sales is B2?

Comment: @hello11 Yes. Create a table and you will see